# SF Flow Endless Spinner On Save

Tags: visual-workflow, error, winter22

I can't `Save As` in a salesforce flow. All I get is an endless spinner. This is the first time I encounter this issue. It appears to be affecting other people on my team as well.

[image]

Additionally I have a pending request from this action in the Networking tab that never seems to complete.

[image]

After a long time, maybe 5mins I am getting a timeout and this message.

[image]

Is anybody else having this problem? Could this be related to the Winter '22 update?

Comment: Did you check the Developer Console (F12)? It might reveal more information. Either way, you should definitely contact support.

Comment: @sfdcfox There's nothing in the developer console and we did contact support. Thank you.

Comment: This is a Known Issue in Winter 22:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002BkwwQAC